# how can I convert time stored in a string variable to time format?

Tags: c++, string, time

I googled some topics on this, but they all seem quite vague.

I have 4 string variables, containing time representing the begin time and end time of 2 events in the format "17:30" or "01:20" etc.

I want to write a function to determine whether they clash or not. So what I'm looking for is something like

```
string beginTime1 = "01:30";
string beginTime2 = "03:30";
string endTime1 = "01:30";
string endTime2 = "01:30";
time begin1, begin2, end1, end2;

begin1 = toTime(beginTime1);
begin2 = toTime(beginTime2);
end1 = toTime(endTime1);
end2 = toTime(endTime2);

If (begin2 > begin1 && begin2 < end1)
    return clash;
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Are the events allowed to run through midnight (00:00)?

Comment: No. They start no earlier than 06:30 and end no later than 20:30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boost Posix Time Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) has a function to get a posix_time value from a `std::string`: [`from_string()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#ptime_from_string).

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean for two events to "clash"?  This happens when one starts before the other ends.  So `begin1 < end2 || begin2 < end1`.

If your times are always formatted like `HH:MM`, there is no need to convert them to another format before converting, because the lexicographical order is already correct.